# How do I reference LD_LIBRARY_PATH with Hypnotoad?

Tags: mojolicious, hypnotoad

I have a Mojolicious application which accesses Net::LDAP.  The application fails to find the libssl.so.

How do I add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to Hypnotoad?  I did this with Apache to solve a similar problem but can't find how to do it for the Hypnotoad server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like this before and it has worked:

```
BEGIN {
$ENV{NLS_LANG} = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8';
}
```

Just replace `NLS_LANG` with the environment variable of your choice.